# How to structure a data analysis paper

Tags: writing, data

There's a large, publicly available data-set that, in my opinion, has been horribly under-analysed. I can only find one paper that seems to use the data from it and I think there's some significant value in going through that data, identifying trends and performing a proper analysis of it.

That being said, I've never written a paper that's purely based on analysing a pre-existing dataset before. I'm used to the hypothesis, test, analyse, conclusion sort of structure, so this is alien territory to me.

I believe that there are 4 categories of data within the set that would benefit from being explored somewhat separately, although they're not entirely distinct.

As things stand, I can think of two possible ways of structuring my article:

```
data/
├─ cat a
├─ cat b
├─ cat c
analysis/
├─ cat a
├─ cat b
├─ cat c
conclusions/
```

Or

```
cat a/
├─ data
├─ analysis
cat b/
├─ data
├─ analysis
cat c/
├─ data
├─ analysis
conclusions/
```

However, neither of these feel quite right and I'm not really sure where I'd put the analysis of where cat a might imply x about cat b. I'm also not really sure what (if anything) I'd write in terms of methodology, since most of the work is analysis, as the data has already been collected.

Is there a sort of standard approach to this? If not, what would people recommend?

Comment: "Analysis" is too broad a term. You don't say what kind of analysis. Descriptive only? Perhaps you do have a hypothesis about what is buried in the data. There is no way to help given what you've said.

Comment: Primarily descriptive, although I'm expecting that this will unearth some interesting avenues of further research. Essentially aiming on prying out the actually useful information (so interesting trends etc.) from the raw data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are running into this problem because there is a deeper issue. Namely, you haven't identified a story or message that you want to tell with this paper.

Now, there's nothing wrong with analyzing old data sets and publishing the results. There are many quite good papers that do this (admittedly I don't know what field you are in; possibly you would need to consider publishing in a journal outside of your norm). There are many possible reasons to write such a paper, for example:

1. There is a new analysis method that can be applied to old data to obtain new results.
2. There is a new insight that you've found in the data that people hadn't appreciated before.
3. Given knowledge of some major event that happened later, you can retroactively look at historical data to see if there were hints in old data preceding that event.
4. The dataset is particularly complete and can be used as a baseline to compare future results to.

Each of these possibilities suggests a different structure for the paper. Using the examples above:

1. Write a section explaining the new analysis method(s), give a brief review of the data set, and present the results of your new analysis.
2. Review the data set and how it was analyzed previously, explain what feature was not appreciated and if possible why it was not appreciated, and present your new insight.
3. Review the historical and new data, then present the results of your analysis of the historical data.
4. Explain why the data set is very interesting and complete and show what performance metrics are achieved in different categories.

I think the issue you are running into is that "we analyzed some old data because it was there" is not in itself a very compelling idea for a paper. I think there is very likely more to it than that, but you just haven't articulated this clearly (to us and maybe to yourself). You wrote, "in my opinion, [the dataset] has been horribly under-analysed." *Why* do you think this? Are you expecting to find something interesting that was missed? Do you think it is a good data set for benchmarking? If you are "just fishing" through old data to see if there's anything there, be aware there's a risk to doing that precisely because it might turn out that you don't find anything interesting and don't have a new method to present.

So, I think you need to clarify why this project is interesting (perhaps for yourself). Once this is clear, then the structure of the paper should follow naturally from how to logically communicate that information.

Comment: Item 4 is the one that I think applies, as far as I can tell it is *the* most complete dataset in the area. I suspect, that the apparent lack of analysis is because the body that collated the data (the ESA) did so to support commercial operations, rather than for research, and it's either just not caught the interest of researchers, or that analysis has been done commercially and kept in-house rather than being published. I'm not *just fishing*,

Comment: The main reason I want to do this is twofold: 1) I think extracting the key trends and interesting findings from the raw dataset is fundamentally useful... 2) I'll be using these findings to inform which area I focus on in a future project

Comment: @ScottishTapWater Great! I think that sounds like it could be a very good paper. In that case, since it sounds like people in the field may not be very familiar with the dataset, I think starting with a review of the dataset makes sense, then highlighting the key results of each part. (So probably the first structure you suggested). One way to do dependencies is to make the analysis part cumulative, so the section analyzing part b of the data will be informed by what was learned in earlier sections analyzing part a.

Comment: Great, thanks! A quick question on your last point, how would you deal with circular dependencies in that format? Would it just be a case of suck it up and add references to later sections where necessary?

Comment: @ScottishTapWater It would be hard to give a general formula. Sometimes what I do is try to imagine explaining the key results to a friend, then use my informal flow of ideas to inform the most logical order to present things in. A few options would include... (a) Have a few sections analyzing each part in isolation, then a later section or sections analyzing combinations of data sets, (b) identify a few key messages or trends you want to convey and devote a section to each one, pulling from whatever parts of the data are needed in each section, (c) say "we will return to this point later."

Comment: @ScottishTapWater Another thing that could be interesting to add in the review of the data set is a comparison to other common data sets, especially to highlight strengths and shortcomings.

Comment: That makes sense, thanks for all the advice!

Answer (score 1):

If there is synergy between the groupings then probably the first option. The more distinct they are the more it pushes toward the second. You have to decide.

In the first case you can describe those synergies better in the analysis part since all have been seen already.